# Resizing AIR for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash

I have two files; preloader.swf and game.swf. 
The preloader basically loads the game(.swf). I have a resize event in the preloader, which is fully functioning!

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

stage.stageWidth = stage.fullScreenWidth;
stage.stageHeight = stage.fullScreenHeight;


trace(stage.stageWidth + "x" + stage.stageHeight);
```

These lines are fired at the very beginning of the script.

But the problem occurs when the game.swf is loaded. At first I tried to place the same lines at the beginning of this script, but it did not work. I tried running only the game.swf, but nothing happened. Then I tried just using the stage.stageWidth to figure out the width of the game.swf after it has been loaded in to preloader.swf, but i got an error saying:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

The line was:

```
trace(stage.stageWidth + "x" + stage.stageHeight);
```

What can I do to make sure both the preloader.swf and game.swf is the same size as the device's max? Is the game.swf's size dependent on the preloader.swf's size (if preloader.swf is 360x720, will game.swf automatically be 360x720)?

Thanks :)

Comment: I've been using Flash and AIR for a very long time but I never knew you could actually set `stageWidth`. Try setting `root.width` from your loaded SWF, or set your `Loader` content width after it's loaded.